# ObjCinstance to PIL image

Tags: ios, python-imaging-library, pythonista

I am designing a face recognition system for a course.

For converting I Currently i use Image.writeToFile_atomically_(filename, True)  which saves the image and I can open the image but it is very slow.

I need to be able to convert ObjCinstance into PIL or ui image without saving the image.

Edit:
My problem is the way I convert ObjCinstance is slow because I save the image and then access the image with PIL. I would like to get a faster way to convert ObjCinstance into PIL. Preferably convert within the script.

Comment: Hi John, it would be really helpful if you could be more specific about the exact problem you're having. Is it the slowness of accessing the image? Is it converting the image with your Python library? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @Aaron It is slow to save the image and then access the image with PIL.